# Jquery State & City Select Lists Not Working Correctly in Firefox, Always Passes First Value of Last Select List Set

Tags: jquery, html, cross-browser, selecteditem

I can't seem to find any solution to this problem. I have a select list of states that when a state is selected another list of cities that corresponds to the selected state is shown. The user then selects a city, submits the form and the value of the selected city is passed via the POST method.

If the user decides to change the state after having already selected one, the previously selected city should be de-selected so a new city can be picked and only it's value passed when submitted.

This works as intended in Chrome and Safari, but not in IE and Firefox. It seems that IE and FF are passing the value of the first option element of the last list displayed.

Any solutions or workarounds to this issue would be greatly appreciated as I'm getting nowhere on this.

Here's what I've got so far...

**Demo:** http://www.chrischoma.com/scripts-samples/state-city-select.php

**HTML (HTML5)**

```
<form id="state-city-select-form" method="post" action="/">

<div id="submit">
    <input id="submit-form" type="submit" value="Next &gt;&gt;" />
</div>

<div class="state">
    <div class="label">
        Select Your State:
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <select id="state-select" name="state">
            <option value="">- Please Select Your State -</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="CA" class="city" style="display:none">
    <div class="label">
        Select Your City:
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <select class="city-select" name="city">
            <optgroup label="- Please Select Your City -">
                <option value="Los Angeles">Los Angeles</option>
                <option value="San Francisco">San Francisco</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="KY" class="city" style="display:none">
    <div class="label">
        Select Your City:
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <select class="city-select" name="city">
            <optgroup label="- Please Select Your City -">
                <option value="Louisville">Louisville</option>
                <option value="Bowling Green">Bowling Green</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="WA" class="city" style="display:none">
    <div class="label">
        Select Your City:
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <select class="city-select" name="city">
            <optgroup label="- Please Select Your City -">
                <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
                <option value="Tacoma">Tacoma</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery (Using Version 1.7.1)**

```
$(function() {
    $('#state-select').change(function(){
        $('.city').hide();
        $(".city-select option").removeAttr("selected");
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following after `$('#' + $(this).val()).show();` , two more lines

```
 $(".city-select").each(function(){$(this).attr("name","");});
 $("#"+$(this).val()+" .input .city-select").attr("name", "city");
```

this works because you have more elements with the same name and i don't think if firefox cares if you've hidden them

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you so much! That works perfectly. A little validating to ensure a selection was made and I'm all set. I owe you one man.

Answer (score 1):

Using the OPTGROUP tag isn't a good way to allow a not-selected state for a single group of options.  It's really designed for categorizing options into sets.  Instead, you need a blank value option if you don't want to default to the first option.  You should change your optgroup into an option, like you have in your state select box:

```
<option value="">- Please Select Your City -</option>
```

And then in your jQuery, replace this:

```
$(".city-select option").removeAttr("selected");
```

with this:

```
$(".city-select").val("");
```